# How to solve $x^3-x^2+2x-1=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Recently I took an exam where it appeared the following equation:

$$x^3+x^2-1=0$$

On the exam we only needed to aprox. the root to the first decimal. However Wolframalpha says that there is a "computable" root.

I tried to work it out by trigonometric substitutions and the following:

$$(x^3+x^2-1)(x^3-x^2+1)=x^6-x^4+2x^2-1$$
Now:

$$x^2\to x$$

We get $$x^3-x^2+2x-1=0$$

From where I get nothing.

Is there anyway to work out manually the roots? And whether a third degree polynomial equation which you know that has a "computable" root can be manually worked out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the Cardano's formula

Comment: Title isn't same with problem.

Comment: @arberavdullahu Look the computations...

Comment: Hm, I'm honestly not familiar with this method involving multiplying by another cubic.  Do you happen to know it's name?

Comment: FYI, all third degree polynomials can be solved (or worked out), though you may run into casus irreducibilius, unless you pursue the solution involving trig functions like in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=x^3+x^2-1$; then $f'(x)=3x^2+2x$, which vanishes at $-2/3$ and $0$. Therefore $f$ has a local maximum at $-2/3$ and a local minimum at $0$. Since
$$
f(-2/3)=-\frac{8}{27}+\frac{4}{9}-1=\frac{-8+12-27}{27}=-\frac{23}{27}
$$
we see that the equation has exactly one real solution. Since $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=1>0$, we know that this root is in the interval $(0,1)$.

For approximating the root we can use [Newton’s method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method):
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$$
starting at $x_0=1$. Then
$$
x_1=1-\frac{1}{5}=\frac{4}{5}=0.8
$$
and
$$
x_1=\frac{4}{5}-
\frac{\dfrac{4^3}{5^3}+\dfrac{4^2}{5^2}-1}
     {3\dfrac{4^2}{5^2}+2\dfrac{4}{5}}=
\frac{4}{5}-\frac{1}{5}\frac{64+80-125}{48+40}=
\frac{4}{5}-\frac{19}{5\cdot 88}=\frac{333}{440}\approx0.7568
$$
Since the method provides alternatively an approximation by excess and one by defect, we can conclude the first decimal digit is $7$.

To check again,
$$
f(0.7)=-0.167,
\qquad
f(0.8)=0.152
$$
so the first decimal digit is $7$.

Actually Cardan's formulas give you “explicitly” the root. Set $y=1/x$; then the equation is $y^3-y-1=0$; by Cardan's formula the only real root is
$$
y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{27}}}
+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{27}}}
\approx 1.32471795724474602596
$$
and
$$
x=\frac{1}{y}\approx0.75487766624669276005
$$
According to `bc`, with this value for $x$ we get
$$
f(x)=-0.00000000000000000001
$$
so it seems a pretty good approximation.

---

Your transformation can work as well, but it's more complex. Consider
$$
g(x)=x^3-x^2+2x-1
$$
Then $g'(x)=3x^2-2x+2$ has negative discriminant, so the function $g$ is increasing. Its zero is between $0$ and $1$, and you can find it with a similar method. Then you need to find its positive square root.

Comment: :D And there is closed form for ya.

Comment: May I suggest Newton's method? I would've written an answer, but it would just be rewriting half of your answer. The reason I'm suggesting it because $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^3+x_n^2-1}{3x_n^2+2x_n}$ will give $\approx 0.7568$ in second iteration starting with $x_0 = 1$ (and you get $x_1 = 0.8$, so it is very doable by hands).

Comment: @Ennar I'd say go for a full numerical method answer, since this answer isn't really about numerical methods.

Comment: @Ennar You can surely suggest a better method! However, the iterative method starting with $x_0=1$ gives $0.707\dots$ at the first step, so the check is whether $f(0.7)<0$ and $f(0.8)>0$.

Comment: egreg, I wouldn't call it better, but I'd say easier to do by hand calculations than calculating a radical.

Comment: @Ennar I implemented it; the computations are indeed not overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

If we start with your first line:

$$x^3+x^2-1=0$$

and let $x=\frac23y-\frac13$ and multiply both sides by $\frac{27}2$ so that we end up with

$$4y^3-3y-\frac{25}2=0$$

Recall that $4y^3-3y=\cosh(3\operatorname{arccosh}(y))$ so that we have

$$\cosh(3\operatorname{arccosh}(y))=\frac{25}2$$

and solving for $y$,

$$y=\cosh\left(\frac13\operatorname{arccosh}\left(\frac{25}2\right)\right)$$

$$x=\frac23\cosh\left(\frac13\operatorname{arccosh}\left(\frac{25}2\right)\right)-\frac13\approx0.754877666$$

and this is the only real root.

Comment: @Dr.MV See here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/simple-arts-new-name

Comment: @Dr.MV He gave me a name I liked better is all :D

Comment: @Dr.MV See here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/conversation/this-is-my-name-for-ya

Comment: @Dr.MV Lmao, I know that one.  :D

Comment: You've heard that your whole life - and that gives you insurance.